# C# error : An object reference is required for the non-static field

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I've found many solutions on this but none of them make sense to me. Basically I'm submitting a form using jQuery AJAX and trying to update a row already in my table but get the error: An object reference is required for the non-static field. If I change the "txtContactLastEdit.Text;" to "New Name;" everything is fine. It's only when I refer to the txt field on the form. Any ideas?
Thanks!

```
[WebMethod]
public static string updateProject(int id)
{
    using (dbPSREntities5 myEntities = new dbPSREntities5())
    {
        // Query for a specific customer. 
        var proj =
            (from tbProject in myEntities.tbProjects
             where tbProject.ProjectID == id
             select tbProject).First();

        // Change the name of the contact.
        proj.ProjectContactLastName = txtContactLastEdit.Text;

        // Ask the DataContext to save all the changes.
        myEntities.SaveChanges();

        var myResult = "success";

        return myResult;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not access the page control inside the Static Method.

You probably calling this method from client side, So one alternative is that send the `txtContactLastEdit.Text` from the client side and change your function to accept that paramter.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string updateProject(int id, string textBoxValue)
{
  // your code.
}
```

Comment: Right. When I delete "static" and submit the AJAX, I get an error: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method updateProject.

Comment: Yes, I had to send the value of txtContactLastEdit to the static method with AJAX. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass the value of the textbox to the `static` method

```
WebMethod]
public static string updateProject(int id, string contactName)
{
    ....

        // Change the name of the contact.
        proj.ProjectContactLastName = contatcName;


}
```

Inside a static method you cannot use instance variables of the class in which the static method id defined, and the `txtContactLastEdit` is an instance variable of the Page of type TextBox. So, supposing that the static method belongs to a class named Project, then you could call it from somewhere in your page.

```
int projectID = 1;
Project.updateProject(projectID,txtContactLastEdit.Text);
```